# Value of an industry postdoc for an R&D career in industry

Tags: career-path, postdocs, industry, engineering

I see lot of industry postdoc positions these days. I am interested in working for industry (R&D/product development) and not academia. But would a industry postdoc be helpful to find a good job in industry? Or would it be better to get a regular job & get experience that way?

I know postdocs are seen as necessary in biological sciences, even for industry jobs. But is that so for engineering too?

P.S: Industry postdocs are what companies like Genentech, Pfizer have introduced trying to bridge academia with industry.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What's the difference between _industry postdoc_ and _industry post PhD_?

Comment: By _a good job in industry_, do you mean permanent positions such as scientists while by _industry postdoc_ you mean short term appointments such as 1 -2 years contractors? **Please clarify**. If this is what you mean, I am afraid this is not the right site for your question. We are Academia SE.

Comment: *Research* jobs in industry are on topic here. It might help if you would [edit] your post to clarify what kind of job you are hoping for, what you mean by a "regular" job, etc.

Comment: @scaaahu - I have edited the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I think the connection with Academia SE is that the OP is wondering whether a postdoc of some sort is as necessary/helpful in engineering as he has noticed it is in, for example, biology.

Comment: @aparente001 What's the reason for the new tag? We generally try to create tags only when they are unambiguous, it is clear when and why to apply them to new questions, and they are clearly distinct from existing tags. This one is not (to me)

Comment: @ff524 - R&D seems to me to be worthy of making a new tag, but if you don't, feel free to delete it.

Comment: @aparente001 It's not really clear to me how it's distinct from [tag:research]. (And both research and research-and-development do not seem like suitable tags for this post, which is not about *doing* R&D, but is more about a career-path)

Comment: @ff524 - Perhaps you'd like to pose a question about this on Meta, instead of discussing it here....  Alternatively, as I said, if you feel quite sure, I will not be offended if you want to uproot this fledgling tag before it gets woody.

Comment: @SRK - In addition to the helpful answers from Jake and Danny -- I think there are academic postdocs available with groups that have a strong tie to industry.  That would be another way of preparing for a job in industry.  On the other hand, if someone wants to hire you in a permanent position doing something you're interested in -- you'd probably want to skip the industry postdoc, and go for the better salary and job security prospects!

Comment: @aparente001- Thank you. The industry postdoc is a new concept ( netherworld between academia & industry). I am finding it hard to get a permanent industry position of liking in engineering R&D. Based on the blogs out there I saw that industry postdocs like at Genentech & Pfizer are sought after (maybe!). I just wanted to get some inputs on whether they would be valuable to for an career in industrial R&D (since I am not interested in academia). The way I see it, companies may want to get the same job done by paying a much lower salary.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no one answer, since there is no standard regulating how companies do things, and typically a great deal of variety from company to company.

If you are looking for a long-term R&D job, however, a postdoc is usually an excellent way to get a foot in the door.  Most big companies are pretty much *always* trying to hire high-quality new people. Since a permanent position hire is generally a fairly long-term investment, they'd really prefer to only hire known quantities if they could.

A postdoc can thus provide a good "getting to know you" trial run for both sides.  By the end of the postdoc, you'll know if you'd like to work at the company long-term, and the people making the hiring decision at the company will know if they want to have you working with them long-term.

Comment: Is this answer generally applicable to engineering companies (not just biological sciences)?

Comment: @scaaahu in my experience, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Any industry experience is relevant when you are applying for a job in industry. As a matter of fact, the content of the experience and the depth are much more important than the form (postdoc, internship, etc).

So, if you seek a job in e.g. telecommunication, make sure your post graduation experience is preferably about telecommunication, and not about something less related, regardless of the form.